# jQuery validation plugin errors as summary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm trying to create a validation summary using the jquery.validation plugin.

What I have so far is this:

```
// Validate order form before submitting it
$('.order-material-form').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {            
        $.each(errorList, function () {
            var element = this.element;
            var labelText = $(element).prev('p').find("label").text();
            var error = this.message;

            errorSummaryList.append($("<li>").text(labelText + ": " + error));
            errorSummaryList.fadeIn('fast');
        });
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css({ "border": "1px solid #ff0000", "color": "#ff0000" });
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css({ "border": "1px solid #555555", "color": "#555555" });
    },
    errorPlacement: function() {}
});
```

This places the errors in my `errorSummaryList` (which is an unordered list), but since it's set to append the errors to the summary list, it keeps appending the same error messages over and over if/when the user switches input etc.

I have an odd feeling that this is not the correct way of creating a summary using the jquery.validation plugin.

Does anyone know how to make this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is a summary list example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {    

    var errorLiArray = $.map(errorList, function(error){
        var labelText = $(error.element).prev('p').find("label").text();

        return "<li>" + labelText + ": " + error.message+ "</li>";
    });

    errorSummaryList.html(errorLiArray.join(''))

    errorSummaryList.fadeIn('fast');

    this.defaultShowErrors();
},
```

Comment: hi jam, thanks a lot! :-) It does seem to work, however, when I set the cursor in a field that's got an error, the summary disappears and only shows the first error field. I must admit that I'm lost using this plugin ;-)

Comment: Screenr of current behavior: http://www.screenr.com/BfI7 It doesn't validate the ´required´ fields before I hit the submit button..

Comment: @bomortensen I haven't used this plugin, so I'm not sure whats wrong (or even if it's a feature :P). Anyways, glad to help out :)

Comment: @bomortensen if you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I may be able to help out :)